# count the # of decimal digits after the radix point

Tags: c++, double

I would like to count the number of decimal digits after the radix point of a floating point number.
The problem obviously raise when the real number doesn't have a representation in the binary system, like `3.5689113`.

I am wondering - if for example someone write this real in a source code - if it is possible to get the number 7 namely the number of digits after the radix point

the naive following code for example doesn't work :

```
int main()
{  
    double num = 3.5689113;

    int count = 0;
    num = abs(num);
    num = num - int(num);

    while ( abs(num) >
        0.0000001 )
    {
        num = num * 10;
        count = count + 1;
        num = num - int(num);
    }

    std::cout << count; //48
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Why is your epsilon only 7 digits? 0.0000001...

Comment: I work with real wich don't have more than 7 digits after the radix point

Comment: Why don't your real numbers have more than 7 digits after the radix point?

Comment: @Mooing: because I work with forex rate, I round the real at the 7 digits at maximum

Comment: A much more interesting number to me is `3.1`. That, also, does not "have a representation in the binary system." Thus, the C++ expression `(double)3.1` does not have a finite number of decimal digits, despite the answer being *obviously* 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a floating point type `T` you can get up to `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` digits restored exactly. Thus, to determine the position of the last non-zero fractional digits you'd use this value as a precision and format the number. To avoid the output using exponent notation you need to set the formatting flags to `std::ios_base::fixed` and account for the number of non-fractional digits:

```
std::ostringstream out;
int non_fraction(std::abs(value) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
                 ? 1: (1 + std::log(std::abs(value)) / std::log(10)));
out << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 - non_fraction)
    << std::fixed
    << value;
```

If there is a decimal point, you just need to count the number of digits up to the trailing sequence of zeros.

Comment: why account for # of non-fractional digits ?

Comment: the more non frational digit there are the less the double will have frational digit to be encoded ?

Comment: There are only a total of `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` digits. If you set the precision to `n` and use `std::ios_base::fixed` there will be `n` fractional digits. This means, that if there are `m` non-fractional digits, you will get `n + m` digits. If `n + m` is bigger than `digits10`, the formatting will start displaying the actual values rather than the digits of the rounded value to fill these digits.

Comment: why not put `std::abs(value) < 1` instead of `std::abs(value) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`

Comment: for `value = 0.0003`, non fraction = -2 so `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 - non_fraction = 17 > 15` this is a matter no ?

Comment: Well, `log(x)` is undefined for very small values but it is defined for values smaller than on. In fact, you even tried it with a value where it matters: 0.0003. In this case it seems to have used precision 17 where it should have used 18, though: the first three fractional zeros shouldn't matter to the number of digits being valid but it discounted only two of them. The fact that precision is bigger than `digits10` shouldn't matter in this case because the precision with `std::ios_base::fixed` is the number of digits after the decimal point and `digits10` doesn't care about leading zeros.

Comment: I will open a new question about stringstream formatting and double, I don"t understand something

Answer (score 3):

When something like that doesn't work, you try to print the numbers.

I did so [here](http://ideone.com/gATI6Z), and I found you had some floating number precision issues.
I changed the `int` rounding to `ceil` rounding and it worked like a charm.

Try putting the `int`s back and you'll see :)

**EDIT:** a better strategy than using `ceil`s (which can give the same rounding problems) is to just round the numbers to the nearest integer. You can do that with `floor(myNumber+0.5)`.

Here's the modified code

```
int main()
{  
    double num = 3.56891132326923333;

    // Limit to 7 digits
    num  = floor(num*10000000 + 0.5)/10000000;

    int count = 0;
    num = abs(num);
    num = num - floor(num+0.5);

    while ( abs(num) >
        0.0000001 )
    {
        cout << num << endl;
        num = num * 10;
        count = count + 1;
        num = num - floor(num+0.5);
    }

    std::cout << count; //48
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you say your reals only had 7 digits? ;)

Comment: yes i'm intersiting by 7 digits at maximum.  std::min(real,7) you will tell me i guess ;)

Comment: Because it violates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer, especially "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: @Oswald, the most important part is "print your numbers" and "change int to ceil".

Comment: @Guillaume07 Hmm, your example does really weird things, numbers just appear from nowhere. This is the precision problem at its maximum

Comment: @Guillaume07 I added a limitation to 7 digits with `num  = floor(num*10000000 + 0.5)/10000000;` and it works. Not very portable though

Comment: What happens if one day you decide your numbers can have 9 digits instead of 7?

Comment: @alestanis, why not convert it to a string and then get the no. of digits after the point? Seems simple to me :)

Comment: @Guillaume07 In one of my former jobs, the IT team had developed a piece of software in FORTRAN that used product codes made of only 10 digits. Several decenies later, they ran out of numbers so they had to start using letters. Kaboum.

Comment: @Aniket because it's very slow :) It depends on the number of times you will have to do the counting, as always. There's a tradeoff between simplicity and efficiency

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the errors introduced by floating point approximation, convert the number to an integer at the earliest possible opportunity and work with that.

```
double num = 3.5689113;

int count = 7;  // a maximum of 7 places
num = abs(num);
int remainder = int(0.5 + 10000000 * (num - int(num)));

while ( remainder % 10 == 0 )
{
    remainder = remainder / 10;
    --count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting to a string, then looping over it and counting how many chars occur after you hit the period. Below is a sample (may need some minor tinkering, been awhile since I've done this in C++);

```
bool passedRadix = false
int i = 0; // for counting decimals
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << dbl; // dbl is 3.415 or whatever you're counting
std::string str = strs.str();

for(char& c : str) {
   if (passedRadix == true)
       i++; 
   if (c == '.')
       passedRadix = true;

}
```